# Get the missing digits of an array

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

I have an array with digits and that array is *not sorted*. The user is able to **delete numbers** from the array. But the user should be able to add the digit later.

Basically I want to write in a database the id. The user is able to remove **rows** but if he add a row the *id should be a missing digit from a deleted row*.

At the moment I solve it like that:

```
for (Object[] object : data) {
    if ((int) object[1] > id) {
        id = (int) object[1];
    }
}
```

But with that I only get the largest number and not the missing number. How I am able to get a missing number?

Example:

> 4, 2, 3, 1 the user deletes row 2 and row 4 so I have
>
> 3, 1 now I want to calculate or with if statements whatever to get the 2 and, if the user add a another row the, 4 back.

Keep in mind that the user could **close** the **program**, so it is **not possible to save** the numbers in a **other array**!

- Thank you for help

Comment: Can you be more clear with your question? Means please give some example.

Comment: Why is `data` an array of `Object`s if it just contains integers?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist This is just a example at the orignal I use the Object because it is data of a JTabel

Comment: can't you somehow sort the data in a temporary storage and find the first missing number?

Comment: @nommyravian yea ok thats not bad at the beginning but now how I get the first missing number of the sorted array? It isne't the biggest and it isn't the smallest so I actully cant use if or?

Comment: so you don't need any random missing number but that specific number what the same user has deleted previously?

Comment: if you have multiple digits missing but have a sorted array now then you would just traverse through the array finding the first missing number. won't you?

Comment: Amm yes that was my question how i "traverse" through and find the missing number?

Comment: i just added the code in the last answer. I doubt this is what you're looking for because it is quite easy to find the first missing number from a sorted array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example, sum the numbers from the beginning to the end, 1+2+3+4 = 10 and subtract the sum of the numbers you have, 1+2+4 = 7

So 10 - 7 = 3 (the missing number)

----------------------------------------------------EDIT ----------------
how about this?

```
public class SandBox7 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] array = new Integer[] { 1, 4, 9 };
    SandBox7 s = new SandBox7();
    List<Integer> mis = s.getMissingNumbers(array);
}

public List<Integer> getMissingNumbers(Integer[] in) {
    int max = getMaximum(in);
    // System.out.println(max);
    List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(in);

    ArrayList<Integer> missing = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i < max; i++) {

        if (!numbers.contains(i)) {
            missing.add(i);
        }
    }
    return missing;
}

private int getMaximum(Integer[] in) {
    int tmp = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < in.length; i++) {
        if (tmp < in[i])
            tmp = in[i];
    }
    return tmp;
}

}
```

Comment: And what if more than one number is missing?

Comment: @Gerret I thought you only needed one, sorry, but in that case, you'll have to save the number at deletion to an collection

Comment: So bassically get the largest number count back and check if the number is in the array. That is a really good solution maybe not the best coding style :D but thank you ^^

Comment: I used a similar answer now but basically yours gave me the idea

Answer (score 1):

Look at below code..might be helpful

```
    int data[]={1,2,4};
    int i=1;
    for(Object object : data){
        if((Integer)object!=i++)
            break;
    }
    System.out.println(i-1);//This will print 3.
```

Comment: Please explain the if statement for me

Comment: If statement will check the contiutiy of the sequence. ie It check the 1,2,4 value of `data` with a **so called counter i**  which is incremented after every looping statement and will break when it encounter that 3 is missing.

Comment: Yea but what does i++ +1?

Comment: Yea I am not new to java but I havent seen that yet xD

Comment: @Gerret hope this will work for you and this answer as a correct one.. ;)

Comment: @Gerret : Lets give an example based solution. Lets take 1,2,4,6 is in our `data` variable. Then at first you will find `3` as a missing digit. After that you have to sort the `data` variable and again you can apply the same above procedure to find next missing digit. I hope you are not trying to find all the missing digits in one go.

Comment: @Gerret Above code will work only with sorted array. First sort your array in increasing order then only you can use above approach.

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be maintaining a parallel array which will contain the deleted number.

```
Object[] data = ...;
Object[] delData = ...;
```

So every time you insert/add a new number you need to check that number exists in parallel array or not.

Comment: This is actully not possible because if the user close the program I lose the data of the array and not able to get it.

Answer (score 0):

You have some possibilities, and it is a design problem *you* have to decide yourself. Just some alternatives:

1. Best: renumber IDs on deletion, but needs meta information on referencing foreign keys.
2. If the data is ordered by ID.
   The numbers of deletions when not renumbered:

   ```
   int deletions = data.length
                   - (data.length == 0 ? 0 : data[data.length - 1][1]);
   ```

   With a binary search, you can find a deleted hole (shifted number).
3. Unordered. Keep the number of deletions maybe.
   Keep an unbounded `BitSet` of `data.length` bits.

   Or alternatively a `Set<Integer>` with deletions. And renumber when the set becomes too large. (A set of ranges from-ID upto to-ID would be better.)

Comment: I do not understand your code may you could make it simpler or explain it to me? And I can't renumber the IDs because it would take to long! At the moment I do not use multitasking so the user has to wait till all database rows are edited.

Comment: If you delete i out of n, you could copy n to i and decrease n. Probably also not fitting. _Maybe you should really look at an embedded database, like the java Derby, HSQL or whatever. It offers persistence too, and queries._

Answer (score 0):

If you sort the id's in a temporary storage so it would be simple to find the first missing number;

```
int arr[] = {0,1,2,5}; //think you've the sorted array now
int missing = arr.length; //would have the last id+1 if there is no missing id
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (i != arr[i]) {
         missing = i;
         break;
    }
}
System.out.println(missing); //3 will be printed.
```